# Maui with Material Design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, maui

I am building a Maui App for the first time and want to employ Material Design. I normally use MahApps or Material design depending on the project. However, when adding the resource dictionary I get a Uri error

```
 <Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Presentation"
    x:Class="Presentation.App">
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesignLightTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The code blows up everytime but if I miss out the last 3 resource dictionaries (those referring to Material Design) I get no issues. I've added Material Design as a NuGet package as well as the extensions. Can anyone see anything daft that I have done???

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4398

Comment: Have you tried to use MaterialDesign for WPF in MAUI? I don't think this possible for now.

Answer (score 1):

Dotnet MAUI has Material UI for Android as default now. You can include the material ui just by adding `using Google.Android.Material` line in your Android folder. Refer this [forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/819386/how-to-implement-material-design.html) for detailed steps.

Comment: I don't understand, where shall we include this line exactly? In the forum and forum links the answer is not clear. I added it to MainApplication.cs under Android folder but has no effect. I don't even understand how using can give such effect by the way..

Comment: @OzanYasinDogan Basically you need to create a new PlatformView in your Handler and use Material Components in it a good example of this is https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/wiki/FreakySwitch that I created, you can check the code in that codebase for an in-depth understanding