# What version of material design does MAUI support out of the box?

Tags: material-design, maui

We are working on a project that a designer is asking these questions as he mocks up our screens.  So far looking around I have some that say material design is supported out of the box with MAUI, but it appears that a combination of Material 1/2 and even some three is used (at least that is what our designer has pointed out).

Does anyone know what version of material design MAUI supports out of the box?

I have attempted to search forums, MS docs, and stack for answers.  So far, I have seen mixed responses but nothing solid.

Comment: Can this cas which is about [Maui with Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438947/maui-with-material-design) help you?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - thank you, I have seen that but it does not specify a version.  I am specifically looking for whether it supports material 2 or 3 out of the box.

Comment: You can try the newest version.